# Getting Javascript console for Cordova Application

Tags: android, ios, extjs, cordova, sencha-touch

Is there any way to get the JavaScript console like the one from Chrome dev tools in Android or iOS device.

I am using Sencha Touch 2.3.1 to create native iOS and Android app using Cordova (PhoneGap).

Comment: if you want for android its Log.v("some console data"); you want javascript console to android ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can say only for iOS, is possible with Safari developer tools, see details in doc [About Safari Web Inspector](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/GettingStarted/GettingStarted.html)

Answer (score 0):

For iOS just use Xcode to build and test your app. You then have a console in Xcode where you can write debug messages to as usual with `console.log()`. This console is available when launching the app into the simulator and into a connected iOS device as well.

Answer (score 0):

Install this phonegap plugin into your project.

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-console